# How do you organize gettext translation files which REGIONALISED?

Tags: zend-framework, local, gettext, zend-translate

My application is i18n but with region difference, that's mean, I'll need to have such translations:

- ch_DE
- fr_FR
- cn_HK
- ru_RU

etc...

In the Zend_Translate documentation it's said that you can use the following structure :

```
/languages
  /en
    lang.en
    other.en
  /de
    lang.de
    other.de
```

Will Zend_translate work with regionalized folder like ch_DE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about to use `gettext` use the gettext standardized `locales` directory to put your localized files.

This looks like:

```
 locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/mydomain.mo 
 locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES/mydomain.mo 
 locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/mydomain.mo
```

Comment: Ok thnak you for your answer, but what about the fallback? Let say I've fr_FR and ch_FR if a translation is not found in ch_FR will it fallback on fr_FR or do I need to have a separate fr/ folder?

Comment: Just write your locale names using [canonical form](http://blog.i18n.ro/simplified-locale-codes/) and it will pick the best one. So, it's best for just go for `en` and `fr` codes to maximize the coverage, considering that probably you are not going to translate it `en_GB` :)

Comment: Yeah It's finaly what I did, I did en/ and fr/ folder, and fr_CH and fr_QC for Swiss & Quebec because there are some specific term, then I set to fr_CH depending of my site, and it'll pick in fr/ if not found in fr_CH.